# Rails 5: select from drop-down menu for edit action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, view

I have view *common/roles/index.html.erb* where I can click un user name, which opens particular user roles for edit action:

```
<ul class="users">
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
<% company.users.each do |user| %>
    <% for role in user.roles %>
    <li><%= link_to user.name, edit_common_role_path(role.id) %></li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Users are found by all users belonging to current_user companies. User ID is placed in roles table in "user_id" column.

In my controllers/common/roles_controller.rb I have this:

```
def index
@roles = current_user.roles
if @roles.any? { |role| role.viewer_rights? || role.editer_rights? ||
 role.creater_rights? || role.deleter_rights? }
  @viewer_editer_creater_deleter = true
else redirect_to errors_path
end
@companies = current_user.companies.includes(:users)
end

def edit
@roles = current_user.roles
if @roles.any? { |role| role.editer_rights? || role.creater_rights? || role.deleter_rights? }
  @editer_creater_deleter = true
else redirect_to errors_path
end
@companies = current_user.companies.includes(:users)
@roles = Role.find(params[:id])
end
```

**How to create drop-down menu, where when particular user selected, user role info for edit action is loaded below drop-down menu?** From there I would need to be able to do update action with "submit" button. It would be nice to do this without re-loading page. Thank you for any help!

**Update**

I have created this in view, which gives me drop-down where I can select users:

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <% company.users.each do |user| %>
   <option value="<%= user.id %>"><%= user.name %></option>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now I need to add functionality, which on select leads to edit page for particular user roles. An option could be to load role info for particular user in this view and then with Submit button save changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve similar functionality without JQuery.

In your routes,

```
get '/edit_common_role', to: 'common_roles#edit'
```

In view,

```
<% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <% company.users.each do |user| %>
    <%= form_tag '/edit_common_role', method: :get do %>
      <%= select_tag :id, options_from_collection_for_select(user.roles, 'id', 'name') %>
      <%= submit_tag "Go" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I am assuming your role model have `name` method hence `name` is added in collection_from_select. You can change it to anything you want.
The id will be selected and for each id you will get edit page for different common role object.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to implement this, however, my user list is no longer in drop down menu. As I understand, you suggest to have select user from drop-down menu, then roles are loaded, then changes to roles are done and with "Go" button confirmed, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved my first question :) Here is code seems like working for me:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">User name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control m-b" name="users" id="user_list">
    <option value="">Please, select user</option>
      <% @companies.each do |company| %>
        <% company.users.each do |user| %>
          <% for role in user.roles %>
             <option value="<%= user.id %>" data-edit-url="<%= edit_common_role_path(role.id) %>"><%= user.name %></option>
             <script type="text/javascript">
              $('#user_list').change(function() {
              window.location = $(this).find(":selected").data('edit-url');
              });
         </script>
       <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Please, comment if I can optimize or do something better!